# Beginning with WCF services. Where to start?

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to develop WCF services for an application of mine. I am aware of web service concepts and know how to develop them using Java. Now i need to develop .net based WCF services. I know  bits n pieces of .Net. Please guide me to some good tutorials for developing WCF services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's always [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) to quickly get you started, if you have the time to read a book [Programming WCF Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526993.do) by Juval Lowy is a really good in depth resource.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [getting started tutorial on WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) over at MSDN. You might want to check it out.

Other than that, overviews and what-have-you can be found on the [WCF page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are two good posts for quick start:

- [Writing the WCF Hello World App](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_the_WCF_Hello_World_App.aspx).
- [Writing your first WCF client](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_your_first_WCF_client.aspx).

And of course MSDN [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).